# How do i install netcdf in delphi 10.4 community edition?

Tags: delphi, netcdf

Im working on a project in delphi and i would like to install netcdf in delphi 10.4 community edition but there are only tutorials is for Visual studios does anyone have any suggestions on how to set this up

Comment: https://github.com/virtorio13/DelphiNetCDF

Answer (score 0):

At the moment DelphiNetCDF.pas does not contain anything, that needs installation. Just drop this file to some path, that is defined in Search path of your project, and add DelphiNetCDF to uses section of your units.